# How to read a constant value like an email address into Email Tool

Tags: alteryx

I am using an Email Address and have the email address hardcoded into the "To:" property, but prefer to move that email address as a custom workflow constant. What tool can I use to just read that constant value. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do this:

1. Create a Workflow Constant with the email address you want to use:
   [image]
2. Use a formula tool to read the constant into a field
   [image]
3. Check the "Use Field" box and choose the field created in step 2
   [image]

You can replace the constant with an input from a database or a macro to make this more automated as well.